# Nokogiri query for HTML comments contained in JavaScript?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have the following HTML and am trying to get the comments in the script nodes:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
            <!--
            url = 'http://someurl.com';
            -->
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Using this, I get the script nodes:

```
javascript_code = doc.xpath("/html/head/script")
```

But, when adding `comments()` to xpath, it returns nothing:

```
javascript_code = doc.xpath("/html/head/script/comment()")
```

I have no idea why this is not working, it seems like it should be simple. Is it possible to get the comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you parse the document as XML, it will find the comment. However, if you parse it as HTML, Nokogiri will put the entire contents of the script tag into a cdata section. You could then parse it out.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

body = DATA.read

doc = Nokogiri::XML(body)
puts doc.search('/html/head/script/comment()').text.strip 
# puts "url = 'http://someurl.com';"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(body)
puts doc.search('/html/head/script').text.strip 
# puts "<!--\n            url = 'http://someurl.com';\n            -->"


__END__
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
            <!--
            url = 'http://someurl.com';
            -->
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```